# vi editor : Non-text symbols appear while reading

Tags: vim, vi

I am having problem while scrolling and reading a large file through `vi` or `gvim`editor. In the middle of a file, I am seeing a continuous stream of symbols `^@` in blue, like we see often in binary files. However, I don't see them with other editors (e.g. TexEdit in my OS X).

Is it a common problem and is there a way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

add this line to your `.vimrc` file:

```
set display=lastline
```

to understand what  it does, do a `:h 'display'`